# AngularJS Codeigniter form validation array fields not working

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, validation

I have view page, with `ng-repeat`. I have a field with an array type, I have tried field name by keeping `nursing_array` and `nursing_array[]` but both are not working in `Codeigniter` validation. Below is my code what mistake I am doing such type of things I have done hundreds of times but not able to find this time what wrong I am doing.

**View Page,**

```
<div class="col-md-6"  ng-repeat ="nurs in nursing" ng-if="nurs.id" >
        <input type="checkbox"  id="{{nurs.id}}" name="nursing_array"  ng-model="PostJobData.nursing_array[nurs.id]" value="{{nurs.id}}">
        <label for="{{nurs.id}}">{{nurs.name}}</label>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nursing_array[]', 'Nursing', 'required');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey Please check the syntax of set_rule

You are passing  `nursing_array` but validating `nursing_array[]`

Please change nursing_array[]  to nursing_array

Working Example

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nursing_array[]', 'Nursing', 'required');
```

To

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nursing_array', 'Nursing', 'required');
```

Note : This form validation library works only post data ,For more information please refer official documentation https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: Hey anand jain , please change your if condition like this 
        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) === FALSE)  , still not working please update your code...